# Fine grained FFT analysis of an audio file

Tags: audiokit

I'm interested in getting FFT data at many different times in an audio file to build a spectrogram.  How can I query the data at a certain sample instead of using the realtime technique found in the playgrounds?

In other words, how do I tap an audio file without having to play it?

I see AKWaveTable lets me iterate over audio samples, is that really the most efficient way?

```
AudioKit.output = player
try AudioKit.start()
player.play()
let fft = AKFFTTap(player)

AKPlaygroundLoop(every: 0.1) {
    if let max = fft.fftData.max() {
        let index = fft.fftData.index(of: max)
    }
}
```